# Бот не отвечает на ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Одна из команд бота не хочет работать исправно, и я не могу решить эту проблему т.к. я новичок в python.
Вот код:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
async def servers ( ctx ):
    await ctx.send("Тебе нужна информация или играть?")
    if lowered('информация'):
```

Когда пишу команду, бот отвечает, но когда выполняется команда `lowered`, происходит вот такая ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.commandInvokeError 
command raised and exeption: NameError: name 'lowered' is not defined
```

Хотя такая комманда существует и её можно использовать.

Comment: вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Comment: определена ли функция `lowered`? Ошибка именно в том, что она не находися. Покажите, как она выглядит. Определена ли она в том же файле, если определена?

Answer (score 0):

Python не может найти функцию `lowerland`. Если вы копировали код откуда-то - скопируйте его полностью. Если написали сами, то добавьте в начало эту функцию, например так:

```
def lowered(data):
   return 0
```

Также возможно вы перепутали ее с функцией `.lower()` для строк.

Я смогу точнее ответить на вопрос, если вы скажете, что бы вы хотели сделать этим кодом.